# Invalid JSON primitive: error when get the post values in asp.net from jquery ajax method

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am using jquery ajax method and sending email from that method to the asp page method but getting the Invalid Json Primitive error I have used followind code please help if anyone know how to handle this.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "login.aspx/DNSValidation",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"EmailAddress":email.toString()},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    timeout: 6000,

    error: function () {
        alert('AJAX Request Failed');
        ajaxInProgress = false;
    },
    success: function (responseData) {

        Console.debug("Email : " + responseData.d);

        ajaxInProgress = false;
    }

});    //ajax
```

login.aspx page code

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static string DNSValidation(object EmailAddress)
    {
                 List<object> eMail = new JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType<List<object>>(EmailAddress);

        Address product = new Address();

        product.emailaddress = eMail[0].ToString();

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);

        return output;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Replace *data part* in $.ajax() with this:

```
data: {"EmailAddress": "'" + email.toString() + "'"}
```

2) Replace *signature* of your *WebMethod* with this:

```
public static string DNSValidation(string EmailAddress)
{
    Address product = new Address();  
    product.emailaddress = EmailAddress; 
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);          
    return output;  
}
```